# Exuberant Ctags: undocumented extension fields

Tags: ctags, exuberant-ctags

I'm looking at the tags file that Exuberant Ctags generated for my ruby project, and reading the documentation for the Tag File Format:

```
tag_name<TAB>file_name<TAB>ex_cmd;"<TAB>extension_fields
```

My tags file has lots of lines like:

```
MyThing<TAB>lib/my_thing.rb<TAB>/^class MyThing$/;"<TAB>c
```

It's just my burning curiosity, but I can't find any explanation of what the trailing `<TAB>c` extension field indicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After downloading the ctags source (and indexing it with ctags), I see in ruby.c that the extension fields are pretty simple:

```
/*
*   DATA DEFINITIONS
*/
static kindOption RubyKinds [] = {
    { TRUE, 'c', "class",  "classes" },
    { TRUE, 'f', "method", "methods" },
    { TRUE, 'm', "module", "modules" },
    { TRUE, 'F', "singleton method", "singleton methods" }
};
```